# Geopandas each row different crs?

Tags: python, geopandas

I have different shape files which contain polygons on a different coordinate system. When I merge them into a GeoDataFrame the crs attribute is not set. It is a way to set for each row in my GeoDataFrame a different crs?

I have found a postgis way SRID=312;POINTM(-126.4 45.32 15) but I'm not sure if it works on GeoPandas

Answer (score 1):

GeoPandas does not support different CRS for different rows. The geometry column of a GeoDataFrame can only have a single CRS.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reference the CRS of each row as a column, then the following will do the job.

You have to choose a common CRS though, because as said in the other answer only one CRS is allowed per geometry column:

```py
def to_crs_from_crs_col(df, crs_col, target_crs, group_keys=True):
    return df.groupby(crs_col, sort=False, group_keys=group_keys).apply(
        lambda df: df.set_crs(df[crs_col].iloc[0])
        .to_crs(target_crs)
        .drop(crs_col, axis=1)
    )
```

Another way of writing it using a for loop instead of `apply`, but it doesn't allow for `group_keys` usage:

```py
def to_crs_from_crs_col(df, crs_col, target_crs):
    return pd.concat(
        [
            df_.set_crs(crs).to_crs(target_crs).drop(crs_col, axis=1)
            for crs, df_ in df.groupby(crs_col, sort=False)
        ],
    ).sort_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried using @paime answer. But it gave me an error, I think currently, geopandas is using pandas' groupby, so it gave me an error (`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_crs'`)

At the end, I did it with a normal for loop

```
def to_crs_from_crs_col(df, crs_col, target_crs):
    dfs_to_join = []
    for crs, df_ in df.groupby(crs_col, sort=False):
        dfs_to_join.append(
            gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df_["coor_utm_x"], df_["coor_utm_y"], crs=crs)).to_crs(target_crs)
        )
    return pd.concat(dfs_to_join, ignore_index=True)
```